# What is the black, finned, metal part in this picture of a board?

Tags: identification, heatsink, board

Can someone explain what this black part is?

[image]

This a [WLAN module.](https://mikrotik.com/product/R2SHPn#fndtn-gallery)

Comment: The black anodized heatsink?

Answer (score 6):

That's a heatsink. Hence the metal feel (good heat transport), the high surface area (high rate of heat transport through convection), and the black color (high emissivity).

Comment: HaHa ... lucky guess! HeeHee